# Check for specific date format in vba excel 2010 64-bit

Tags: datetime, excel, vba

I'm doing some validations to a cell where the user inputs a date value. The correct format I'm expecting is "m/d/yyyy", so I need a way to check that the user enter the date in that format.

How can I achieve that?

here are some of the validations I've made:

```
Dim StartDate As String
 Dim EndDate As String
 With Sheet1
    StartDate = WorksheetFunction.Trim(.Range("F2").Value)
    EndDate = WorksheetFunction.Trim(.Range("F3").Value)
 End With

 'Dates validations

 If StartDate = "" Or EndDate = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Dates can't be empty")
    Exit Sub
 End If

 If Not IsDate(StartDate) Or Not IsDate(EndDate) Then
    MsgBox ("Please check dates format")
    Exit Sub
 End If

 If CDate(StartDate) > CDate(EndDate) Then
    MsgBox ("Start Date can't be greater than End Date")
    Exit Sub
 End If
```

Comment: Why not use the Excel's inbuilt data validation? That way's you don't have to write any code ;) The user will not be able to type anything else other than dates.

Comment: Hope this helps? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211485. Let me know if you still want help?

Comment: I appreciate your help Siddharth, but by making some tests, I've figure it out how to do it, just like you said, using data validation, I didn't know about that, so, thanks again! Place an answer so I can give you the credit :)

Comment: Glad to be of help ;) Nope not required ;)

Comment: +1 for learning something on your own today ;)

Comment: If you found your own solution, then you should post that as an answer and then mark it as the solution by clicking the tick.  This will ensure other developers know your question is solved and it may help other searching for a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siddharth Rout's solution:

Hope this helps? [support.microsoft.com/kb/211485](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211485).